# Can't access remote EJB

Tags: testing, glassfish, ejb-3.0, integration, jndi

I've created EJB with remote and local interfaces.

```
@Stateless
public class VendorBean implements VendorBeanLocal, VendorBeanRemote {

    ...

}

@Local
public interface VendorBeanLocal {

    ...

}

@Remote
public interface VendorBeanRemote {

   ...

}
```

There are some methods instead of dots (it doesn't matter in this case).

Then deploy it to glassfish 3.1. It's accessible from my client web application (deployed as war on the same server) and works fine. But I can't access it from my integration tests.

I wrote integration test which is supposed to be run by maven 2. I looked JNDI name of this bean in the glassfish server.log:

```
java:global/<my business module name>/VendorBean!<package>.VendorBeanRemote
```

and wrote the test. But I always get exception on lookup:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.ExceptionMapper.mapException(ExceptionMapper.java:61)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callResolve(CNCtx.java:501)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.lookup(CNCtx.java:540)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.lookup(CNCtx.java:518)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at com.widewebtech.mercury.core.test.ejb.VendorBeanIntegrationTest.manageVendor(VendorBeanIntegrationTest.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFoundHelper.read(NotFoundHelper.java:72)
    at org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextExtStub.resolve(_NamingContextExtStub.java:406)
    at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callResolve(CNCtx.java:487)
    ... 33 more
```

The code of test:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory");
p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
Context context = new InitialContext(p);

Object o = context.lookup("java:global/<my business module name>/VendorBean!<package>.VendorBeanRemote");
```

I'm confused. I've read a lot of articles, tried a lot suggestions but nothing works.

I've also tried to list a context within the test:

```
NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list = context.list(""); 
while (list.hasMore()) { 
    NameClassPair ncPair = (NameClassPair) list.next(); 
    System.out.print(ncPair.getName() + " (type "); 
    System.out.println(ncPair.getClassName() + ")"); 
}
```

Result:

```
<package>.VendorBeanRemote__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__ (type com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.CORBAObjectImpl)
SerialContextProvider (type com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.CORBAObjectImpl)
java:global (type com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx)
INITIAL_GIS (type com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.CORBAObjectImpl)
```

So, looks like bean in the context.

What I do wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I've managed to solve this issue. So, the code is:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "corbaname:iiop:localhost:3700");
context = new InitialContext(p);

VendorBeanRemote vendorBean = (VendorBeanRemote) context.lookup("java:global/<my business module name>/VendorBean!<package>.VendorBeanRemote");
```

Important thing, gf-client.jar must be in the classpath. It can be taken from the 
glassfish lib directory.

Comment: It works also without providing any properties, as those you have stated are the default values anyway.

Comment: using the app client container (appclient)or leveraging Java Web Start might be useful for this use-case, too.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is strugling with remote EJB calls between 2 different hosts on glassfish, with the exception stated above:
Set your orb-listener-1 network adress to your IP. (ORB / IIOP listeners section in config)